# Can I use node modules in an existing javascript application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, browserify, webpack

**My goal is to figure out how I can use node modules in an existing javascript application**

My existing application is jQuery and ReactJS based.

I've come across a few node modules I'd like to start using with the project, that appear to be only available as modules (so they can't be used by simply adding a `script` tag).

Previously I'd been using `bower` to install libraries and use them locally simply using `script` tags.

I understand that I can use `Browserify` or `Webpack` to bundle a bunch of Node modules up into a single javascript file, but how can I expose the modules that are in it to my existing app?

What'd I'd like to be able to do is

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="bundle.js"/>
<script src="myapp.js"/>
```

where `myapp.js` can use a global variable for say `module_x` which was an npm module.

One of the problems I foresee is that say `bundle.js` may include jquery already, so how do I address this as well? I know some may say "convert your whole project to modules", then it'll just work! But I'm wondering if it can be done without doing that, despite all the benefits ;-)

Comment: I am new to this stuff and I used Gulp to "build" my modules and scripts into one script.js file... this is then included in my index.html and can be used as you know it. Just read about Gulp and pipe and that good kind of stuff... sorry cant give a more qualified answer to this, so i just tried to help by commenting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not the better practice, but you can use globals with browserify. This way you will be able to access libraries you get with `require()` in any scope you need. Just use:

```
global.lib = require('somelib');
```

Then just **browserify** your source file throught [browserify](http://browserify.org/). If you dont know how, just read the [documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage). Its pretty easy to use.

After that, just access `lib` from anywhere you need it.

Also, if you already defined jQuery as a global previous to the bundle, you will be able to access it into the browserified file. Inside your main browserify file, just:

```
var someVar = require('./somefile.js');
var allDivs = $("div"); // $ was a global before this file runs
```